# Doubts with authentication flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, authorization

I'm developing a server and client aplications. This app will have a social login button with Facebook or Google.
The server app will expose APIs that the client app will consume, but to do this, the client must be authenticated before the server.
This is the flow that i am thinking.

[image]

To solve the authentication using google and facebook  i am thinging to use Implicit Grant flow, but...

1. In my server how can i know the client identity? how the client is authenticated before my server?
2. The client should send a token to my server, how it would work?

Notes:

- The server is a Spring Boot app
- The client is a Single-page application using Angular
- In the future i will develop a Mobile App for the client

Answer (score 0):

The implicit flow has several drawbacks. One of them is that `implicit flow` is less secure than the `authorization code flow` due to lack of client authentication.

> The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and
> relies on the presence of the resource owner and the registration of
> the redirection URI.  Because the access token is encoded into the
> redirection URI, it may be exposed to the resource owner and other
> applications residing on the same device.

You're trying to use the Google or Facebook Authorization servers in your application. Going with `authorization code flow` is much secure than Implicit flow.